# MLFlow install Python 3.10.12 with pyenv-win?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenv, mlflow, pyenv-virtualenv

I'm working with MLFlow 2.7.1 on Windows 10 and when I try to serve a model via `mlflow serve` it tries to use Pyenv to install Python 3.10.12. I installed the latest version of Pyenv Win with pip and updated via `pyenv update`, but when I run `pyenv install --list` it does not list Python 3.10.12. Looking into it I found Pyenv Win does not seem to support Python 3.10.12 and the reason seems to be that python.org does not provide binaries/installers for Python 3.10.12 only source code. I tried modifying the `mlflow\utils\virtualenv.py` to use Python 3.10.11 by setting `version='3.10.11'` but then I got another error. Just wondering if anyone has any ideas on what I can do, or if there is some way I can specify to MLFlow to use a different version of Python than 3.10.12?

The command I am using to serve the model with MLFLow is;

`mlflow models serve -m {path_to_model} -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8001`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--env-manager=local` or `--no-conda` (deprecated) to your command:

```
mlflow models serve -m {path_to_model} -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 --env-manager=local
```

Refer to this post:
[Deploying MLflow Model without Conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158939/deploying-mlflow-model-without-conda-environment)